# UIDatePicker is not giving correct date

Tags: objective-c, uidatepicker

I am using UIDatePicker to select the date. I have selected only DateMode in this. Sometimes, its behaving differently

If i select December 17,2014 in calander. Its giving me the string as selected date is 2014-12-351 and it should be 2014-12-17 instead.

code below is used to get the string from UIDatePicker.

```
  NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD"];
  NSString *selectedDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                              [df stringFromDate:datepicker.date]];
```

Please help me in this

Comment: Use "yyyy-MM-dd".  (And read the [spec](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).)

Comment: yes, i used this format now and its fine this time

Comment: @HotLicks, please put this comment as answer and let Nitya to mark as accepted?

Comment: @x4h1d - You may do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From @Hot Licks comment,**

Use correct date format as `yyyy-MM-dd`. For further reference read [Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)